# mongo query - does property exist?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Within a collection document there is a 'sub' property that is an object containing 1 or more properties. The collection looks like: (I've removes extraneous other properties)

```
"properties": {
    "source": {
        "a/name": 12837,
        "a/different/name": 76129
    }
}
```

I need to do a find on the collection where a/name and a/different/name are variables.

The variables have embedded front slashes because they are mqtt topic names, in case you wonder.

(node.js)

I've tried:

```
collection.find({'properties.source[variable containing name]': {$exists: true}}).toArray(function...
```

Doesn't work, nothing returned

I've also tried setting a query string as in:

```
var q = util.format('properties.source.%s', variable containing name);
collection.find({q: {$exists: true}}).toArray(function...
```

Fails with query error

I could replace the front slashes with some other character if they are the problem but I suspect they are ok.  I have tried escaping the front slashes and it makes no difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use a variable as an object key, so you need to change it to something like:

```
var name = 'a/name';
var query = {};
query['properties.source.' + name] = {$exists: true};
collection.find(query).toArray(function...
```

Comment: JohnnyHK's solution works.  Now I need to see if I can optimize the query.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312836/optimizing-query-for-exists-in-sub-property

Answer (score 0):

As you have `properties` an object and `source` is also an object, You should use [$exist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) in a query like following :

```
db.collection.find({"properties.source.a/name":{$exists:true}})
```